# Как скрывать ненужное и показывать только одно событие в fullcalendar

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

Использую fullcalendar для установки стоимости аренды в сутки либо на определенную дату.
Например аренда в сутки установлена 2100р. с 14.09.18г., далее используется повторение события чтобы не создавать событие на каждый день. А с 25 по 29 создано новое событие со стоимостью 2900р. Как можно убрать этот перехлест? Чтобы с 25 по 29 было только 2900, а дальше снова было 2100р.
Желтым и синим выделены отдельно созданные события.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица MySQL-5.6. На fromDay и customRender можно не обращать внимание.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю данные из базы и формирую массив...

```
//получение событий объекта
public function getDateEvent($idProperty)
{
    $params = [
        'idProperty' => $idProperty
    ];
    return $this->db->row('SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE id_property = :idProperty', $params);
}
```

}

```
$getDataEvents = $this->model->getDateEvent(1);
                $getEvent = [];
                foreach ($getDataEvents as $getDataEvent){
                    $getEvent[] = [
                        'title' => $getDataEvent['title'],
                        'start' => $getDataEvent['start'],
                        'end' => $getDataEvent['end'],
                        'fromDay' => $getDataEvent['fromDay'],
                        'customRender' => $getDataEvent['customRender'],
                        'color' => $getDataEvent['color'],
                        'dow' => $getDataEvent['dow'],
                        'ranges' => [['start'=>$getDataEvent['dateStart'],'end'=>$getDataEvent['dateEnd']]]
                    ];
                }
                echo json_encode($getEvent);
```

В консоли вижу следующее...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В конфигурации fullcalendar вывод делаю так...

```
eventRender: function(event){
        //console.log(event.ranges);
        return (event.ranges.filter(function (range) {

            return (event.start.isBefore(range.end) &&
                event.end.isAfter(range.start));

        }).length) > 0;
    },
```

Comment: *Как можно убрать этот перехлест?* Получить данные в том виде, в каком они нужны, а не в том, в каком "так получилось". Для более осмысленного ответа - недостаточно данных.

Comment: Добавил больше информации.

Comment: *Получаю данные из базы* Где? где текст запроса на получение данных? ясное дело, если просто тянуть из таблицы всё, что там есть - то никакого отсева и не будет. И да - версию MySQL укажите... *Как можно убрать этот перехлест?* В показанной таблице в данных нет никакого перехлёста.

Comment: Добавил запрос к базе. MySQL 5.6.

Comment: Теперь приведите в соответствие показанные данные и утверждение о существовании где-то перехлёста.

Comment: В таблице dow[0,1,2,3,4,5,6] отвечает за повторение события каждый день. id-5 указано повторять до 2028 года. Но id-6 нужно показать с 25 по 29, а id-5 в это время показывать не нужно. Если сделать запись id-5 до 25 числа, то конечно перехлеста не будет, но тогда нужно создавать новую запись чтобы продолжить показывать до 2028 года. К какому соответствию нужно привести данные? На скриншоте видно что с 25 по 29 показываются 2 события.

Comment: O! пардон, трудно углядеть, что там 28-й год... ок.

Comment: Может смотрю не с той стороны и есть смысл при создании нового события дату окончания события до 28 года менять на дату начала нового события и добавлять еще одну запись в которой будет продолжение события?

Comment: Нет, подобная вещь не есть правильно... тем более что есть определённый шанс потерять "стек". Вопрос: данные нужны за длительный период? или за некий диапазон (скажем, месяц)? потому как проще всего сразу на MySQL развернуть исходные данные в посуточные. Жаль, сервер не восьмёрка, там всё это вообще было бы красиво.

Comment: Данные за длительный период к сожалению. Я тоже сначала хотел прописывать каждый день. И с JSON работать на 5.6 не удобно. Изначально администратор указывает ценник за сутки. А далее может указывать цены на определенный период и эти данные должны быть приоритетнее цены за сутки.

Comment: Не, не прописывать. Я про отдачу результата запросом.

Comment: Есть сайт на вордпрес с таким функционалом, там запись в базе организована таким образом, число и цена - a:3:{i:1536796800;d:2000;i:1536883200;d:2000;i:1536969600;d:2000;}

Comment: Может кто подскажет какой-то готовый скрипт с подобным календарем. Желательно чтобы его можно было синхронизировать с Google календарем.